# Bot is not showing in MS Teams when tried to search by Bot App ID

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-node-sdk

We created bot and connected to MS teams channel. its working fine. but now, when I'm tried to search bot in MS teams using MS App ID, it is not showing.
Please find below image for reference.

[teams image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKvZY.png)

when we tried to search by MS APP ID, it displays message like couldn't find any matches.
Can someone please help on that.

Comment: Could you please try searching via App name instead of App Id?

Comment: No its not coming. but last time when I searched using App Id, it displays that bot name in  teams channel. now its not coming.

Comment: Could you please try clearing cache or try uninstall/reinstalling? That might help.

Comment: Do you mean MS Teams app or Channel configuration from Azure Bot? Can you please provide more information on that.

Comment: Try to clear cache of MS Teams app and try uninstall/reinstalling your bot.

Comment: No, its not working. but we recently uploaded it into teams. using app name we are able to search.

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked. Thanks for notifying.